# Error sobre Vector en Java

Tags: java, array, nullpointerexception, error404

Agradecería si alguien me puede ayudar con el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at carpeta.ConfigTeclado.guardaConfig(ConfigTeclado.java:91)

El código (sólo las partes en dónde lo empleo) es el siguiente:

```
public class ConfigTeclado extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener{
    private Vector teclas = new Vector();
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){ }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        Boolean ver=true;
        if(!ban){
            for(int i=0;i<b.length && ver;i++){ 
                 if(b[i].getLabel().equals(e.getKeyText(e.getExtendedKeyCode())))
                ver=false;  
            }
            teclas.add(e.getKeyCode());        
            if(ver){
                a.setLabel(e.getKeyText(e.getExtendedKeyCode()));             
                ban=true;              
            }        
        }
    }

    public void guardaConfig(){ 
        bd.inicializar();             
        bd.actualizarConfiguracion("UP", (int)teclas.elementAt(0));
        bd.actualizarConfiguracion("DOWN", (int)teclas.elementAt(1));
        bd.actualizarConfiguracion("LEFT", (int)teclas.elementAt(2));
        bd.actualizarConfiguracion("RIGHT", (int)teclas.elementAt(3));
        bd.cerrar();
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Una consulta, ¿cuál sería la línea 91 de ConfigTeclado.java?

Comment: Hola Julio, cómo estás? La línea 91 es esta: bd.actualizarConfiguracion("UP", (int)teclas.elementAt(0));

Answer (score 2):

Es posible que bd (en guardarConfig()) tenga valor null o no exista, generalmente un nullPointerException se da cuando intentas cambiar un valor o utilizar un método de algo que realmente no está inicialiazdo o no se le ha asignado un valor a pesar de haber sido referenciado a algún tipo de dato u objeto.

Aunque se lea incoherente porque justamente intentas hacer eso aquí:

```
bd.inicializar();
```

El tema es si bd, en ese momento, era el objeto que requería ser para poder llamar al método inicializar o no.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte tu tiempo en responderme! bd es la base de datos, y cuando se inicializa le cargo valores por defecto. Lo más raro es que me tira el error pero de todas manera se carga y me funciona bien la base.

Comment: Vale, entonces descartamos bd.
Cuando llamas a guardaConfig, estás segura de que **teclas**, tiene algún valor?
Insisto con el tema del nullPointer.
Arriba veo que inicializas
`private Vector teclas = new Vector();`
En ese caso está asignado, pero en ese código no se ve de dónde llamas al método guardaConfig()
¿No será que lo llamas en alguna parte del código en la que en cierta circunstancia **tecla** no está inicializado y/o no tiene un valor?

Comment: No porque donde lo llamo ya está inicializado. Voy a seguir mirando el código, es medio extraño el error. De todos modos muchas gracias por tu ayuda!